# angular js, javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Tags: angularjs

Please let me know how to display the metrics, name, and nodes of the cluster using ng-repeat in a div.

Following is the JSON:-

```
[  
   {  
      "metrics":{  
         "groupMetric_2":"value2",
         "groupMetric_1":"value1",
         "groupMetric_0":"value0"
      },
      "name":"myGroup",
      "clusters":[  
         {  
            "metrics":{  
               "cluster1_1":"value1",
               "cluster1_0":"value0",
               "cluster1_3":"value3",
               "cluster1_2":"value2",
               "cluster1_4":"value4"
            },
            "name":"cluster1",
            "nodes":[  
               {  
                  "metrics":{  
                     "cluster1_node_1_0":"value0",
                     "cluster1_node_1_2":"value2",
                     "cluster1_node_1_1":"value1",
                     "cluster1_node_1_4":"value4",
                     "cluster1_node_1_3":"value3"
                  },
                  "name":"cluster1_node_1"
               },
               {  
                  "metrics":{  
                     "cluster1_node_2_1":"value1",
                     "cluster1_node_2_0":"value0",
                     "cluster1_node_2_3":"value3",
                     "cluster1_node_2_2":"value2",
                     "cluster1_node_2_4":"value4"
                  },
                  "name":"cluster1_node_2"
               },
               {  
                  "metrics":{  
                     "cluster1_node_3_0":"value0",
                     "cluster1_node_3_2":"value2",
                     "cluster1_node_3_1":"value1",
                     "cluster1_node_3_4":"value4",
                     "cluster1_node_3_3":"value3"
                  },
                  "name":"cluster1_node_3"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "metrics":{  
               "cluster2_0":"value0",
               "cluster2_2":"value2",
               "cluster2_1":"value1",
               "cluster2_4":"value4",
               "cluster2_3":"value3"
            },
            "name":"cluster2",
            "nodes":[  
               {  
                  "metrics":{  
                     "cluster2_node_1_4":"value4",
                     "cluster2_node_1_2":"value2",
                     "cluster2_node_1_3":"value3",
                     "cluster2_node_1_0":"value0",
                     "cluster2_node_1_1":"value1"
                  },
                  "name":"cluster2_node_1"
               },
               {  
                  "metrics":{  
                     "cluster2_node_3_4":"value4",
                     "cluster2_node_3_2":"value2",
                     "cluster2_node_3_3":"value3",
                     "cluster2_node_3_0":"value0",
                     "cluster2_node_3_1":"value1"
                  },
                  "name":"cluster2_node_3"
               },
               {  
                  "metrics":{  
                     "cluster2_node_2_3":"value3",
                     "cluster2_node_2_4":"value4",
                     "cluster2_node_2_1":"value1",
                     "cluster2_node_2_2":"value2",
                     "cluster2_node_2_0":"value0"
                  },
                  "name":"cluster2_node_2"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Post the code that you tried and the specific issue with it. If you are expecting some free code from the community, you are at a wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn 2 things to achieve it :

1) How to access elements of Array.

You can access the array values by using the index number.
Example :

```
var myObj, x;
myObj = {
    "name":"John",
    "age":30,
    "cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
};
x = myObj.cars[0];
```

Check it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) to learn more.

**2) How to access properties of Object.**

You can access the object values by using dot (.) notation:
Example :

```
myObj = { "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null }; 
x = myObj.name;
```

Check it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp) to learn more.

Finally, you'll be ready to learn the usage of ng-repeat in AngularJS :

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [
    {
      "Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
      "Country" : "Germany"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Berglunds snabbköp",
      "Country" : "Sweden"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
      "Country" : "Mexico"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Ernst Handel",
      "Country" : "Austria"
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<table ng-controller="myCtrl" border="1">
<tr ng-repeat="x in records">
  <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
  <td>{{x.Country}}</td>  
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```